# ReCaptcha v2 won't load in vue-router navigation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recaptcha, vue-router

I am using Google ReCaptcha v2 which I am integrating it for the registration process. So, when the user goes `/register`, it loads the `RegisterComponent`.

However, the reCaptcha won't load when say I'm in Homepage and navigate to the `/register` via a button. Why is it happening?

I am loading the script in `layouts.master.php`:

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`

And loading the reCaptcha in Register Component like so:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="control" id="recaptcha-reg">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
        <span v-if="regErrors.captcha" v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This reCaptcha is then validated using PHP. So, there's no JS Logic! Please help!

Comment: Check if there is any error in console of the browser.

Comment: @SagarTamang There's no any error initially. But when I try to register the user, I get this `Uncaught Error: No reCAPTCHA clients exist.` error!

Comment: Can you check whether the recaptcha library is installed in the Register Component page or not.

Comment: @SagarTamang What do you mean? The reCaptcha does load when I directly visit `/register` via the browser. But when I access the RegisterComponent via a button in the homepage, the reCaptcha won't load at all :(

Comment: And in `RegisterComponent`, there's only that amount of code as posted in the question!

Comment: I know its a hack but try putting <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script> in your main blade layout file which is loaded everytime.

Comment: @SagarTamang The script is already in the main blade file. I have not put the script in the `RegisterComponent` though.

Comment: @SagarTamang Solved it using `setTimeout`!

Comment: Ok great. It worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone is having the same problem, here's how to solve it:

- Assign the id to your reCaptcha widget.
- And then when the component is created, run `setTimeout` to render the widget.

Example:

```
<div id="recaptcha-main" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
```

And then in your component where you want to load the captcha:

```
created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha-main'); // 'recaptcha-main' is the id that was assigned to the widget
    }, 2000);
}
```

That's it!

**UPDATED - THE BEST APPROACH**

Instead of using `setTimeout`, use `nextTick()` instead which basically runs only after the view incl. the children are finished loading.

You assign the id and then run this inside of your `created` hook:

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
    grecaptcha.render('recaptcha-main');
})
```

The drawback of `setTimeout` is it runs only after the specified time. Say 1 second for example. So, if your component takes >1 second to load fully, then the `setTimeout` may not work here as it will be executed immediately after 1 second.

I hope this works for you :)

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/01/22/vue-what-is-next-tick/

Answer (score 0):

@Damon answer works and is awesome - I thought I'd just post some vue component code to help others implement it:

```
created() { // in whatever component has a recaptcha
    window.sendMsg = this.sendMsg // making the callback function from the vue object available to the google script in the global scope.
    console.log('grecaptcha', grecaptcha)
    this.$nextTick(function() {
        grecaptcha.ready(function() { // making sure the recapcha script is loaded
            try {
                grecaptcha.render('invisibleRecaptcha1') //render the plain-jane recaptcha element with the given id
            } catch (err) { // dont care about errors, because the worst that can happen is maybe it already rendered once.
                err
            }
        })
    })
}
```

The idea is just that you should put the google script tag in `head` as normal, then use the simplest static integration tag:

```
<button id="invisibleRecaptcha1" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc7hdkZ**********************" data-callback="sendMsg" data-action="submit">Shout!</button>
```

Where `sendMsg` is whatever function you are guarding with the recaptcha.